# Open port 8080 on D-Link DSL-6740U

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to use port forwarding to open port 8080 on my router, but am getting the following message:

[image: Not allowed]

This is the configuration I am trying to use:

[image: Port forwarding configuration]

Anyone knows why this is happening and if there is a way to go around it?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**
Adding the web interface site map:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually it turned out that my ISP company that provided me the router in the first place (years ago) tampered with it and blocked opening those ports on the firmware level. Had to change a router since firmware upgrades also don't work due to their tampering.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love these consumer routers.  D-Link is especially confusing because it hides common network settings under more "user friendly" names.  I'm surprised it says "Port forwarding setup".

Having said that, I'd check the web interface for terms like "Application Rules" or "Virtual Server" and see if any of those ports are already being forwarded as a part of those "user friendly" settings.

You might also look under any section in the interface that might show port forwards automatically setup by UPnP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It is indeed confusing.. What I know pretty much for sure is that the port isn't open, since I am unable to access my tomcat server on the computer connected to this router, while I am able to connect to it on another computer connected to a different router (which allows opening port 8080). Under UPnP I section I see nothing but enable/disable UPnP Protocol. Failed to find "Application Rules" nor "Virtual Server" I have added the site map for any other Ideas. Thanks !

Comment: the machine that is listening on 8080 .. is that really 10.0.0.1?  usually .1 in a typical config is used as the gateway.  Also curious about the error message saying "10.0.0.138 says .."  if the external IP is in the same block as the internal, that may be a cause for problems.  the oddity may be in the way the config is using pppoe

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! Under LAN setup I defined my machine's MAC address to 10.0.0.1 statically. All the other port forwarding records are set to 10.0.0.1 and the port to open (i.e. 8888) and it works fine. The only port I am getting that popup message for is 8080 (for some strange reason). 10.0.0.138 is the default gateway (with which I also access the web interface). I am not sure what you mean by "if the external IP is in the same block as the internal". I don't believe that is the case since my external IP begins with 79.